# Visual Studio for Mac creates 2 .apk archives, one with -signed.apk

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

When I create a release archive of a Xamarin Android app in the latest release of Visual Studio for Mac (8.1.3 build 19), I end up with two .apk's, with filenames like:

- com.whatevs.android.apk
- com.whatevs.android-signed.apk

Why does it do this? What can I change in my project setup to prevent it? If it can't be prevented, then which one is the appropriate file to upload to Google Play?

This actually used to be a problem a year ago or so, but went away, and now it's back...

Comment: The "signed" one is for Play Store.

Answer (score 2):

The major differences are the debug flag and the signing keys, I guess. You can read more about signing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=macos) and manually signing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/manually-signing-the-apk).

Answer (score 2):

This happen when you build the app and create an archive for publishing with a physical device selected in Visual Studio for Mac as target device. 
Select an emulator, Build all and Archive for publishing.